# String representation of django model to show non-default model fields only

Tags: django, django-models

If I have a model with many fields with default values, is there any way to configure a string representation to show non-default values only. i.e.:

```
from django.db import models

class Config(models.Model):   
    debug = models.IntegerField(default=7)    
    retry = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        # here is where the magic would go
        # if debug is at default value (7), do no show it, otherwise skip
        config_str = ['generic config']
        for field in self._meta.get_all_field_names():
            config_str.append('%s=%s' % (field, getattr(self, field, None)))
        return ' '.join(config_str)
```

Such that `str(Config(retry=True, debug=7))` would be `'generic config'` but `str(Config(retry=True, debug=8))` would be `'generic config debug=8'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this seems to be doing the job. Let me know if there is a better way to do this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    config_details = ['generic config']

    for field_name in self._meta.get_all_field_names():
        # it is important to list all related objects here too, 
        # otherwise strange things may happen
        if field_name in ('id', ):
            continue
        value = getattr(self, field_name, '')
        default_value = self._meta.get_field(field_name).get_default()
        if (value !=default_value):
            det_str = '%s=%s' % (field_name, value)
            config_details.append(det_str)

        return ' '.join(config_details)
```